# Can count() be called twice in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am using structured streaming loading records from redis, the code is below

```
val image = spark.readStream.format("redis").schema(...).load()
val q = image.writeStream.foreachBatch { 
  (batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) => {
    logger.info(batchDF.count()) // INFO: 4 (or other number)
    logger.info(batchDF.count()) // INFO: 0
    logger.info(batchDF.count()) // INFO: 0
  }
}.start()
q.awaitTermination()
```

As shown above, the first `logger.info` seems get correct count of `batchDF` but from the second one it is 0.

What's more important, has `batchDF` gone after the first `count()`?

Comment: Not reproductible, are you sure this is the code you are running? The RDD is not getting consumed.

Comment: Please give a full [mcve].

Comment: @BlueSheepToken The question has been modified, sorry for the previous mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *So after count() is called once, is the RDD still there?*

-- **Yes, you can run multiple action over RDD. It exits till spark session alive.**

To check count is zero or not. You can use `rdd.isEmpty` function like below:

```
if(rdd.isEmpty)
{// means count is zero
} else {//means not zero}
```